# Google Dataprep: Scheduling with updated data source

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

Is there way to trigger dataprep flow on GCS (Google Cloud Storage) file upload? Or, at least, is it possible to make dataprep run each day and take the newest file from certain directory in GCS?

It should be possible, because otherwise what is the point in scheduling? Running the same job over the same data source with the same output?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this product is very immature at the moment, so no API endpoint exists to run a job in this service. It is only possible to [run a job in the UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Run-Job-Page_57344897#run-job).

In general, [this is a pattern](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/06/Reliable-task-scheduling-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html) that is typically used for running jobs on a schedule. Maybe at some point the service will allow you to publish into the "queue" that `Run Job` already uses.